# validates_presence_of in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have a model. i want import in this model a module.
in this module i want insert a validates_presence_of for the models that import it

I want know if and how is possible to do something like this:

```
class Ele < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Mod
end

module Mod
   validates_presence_of     :field
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in app/models/awesome_model.rb

```
class AwesomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

 inlude ModuleName

end
```

in lib/module_name.rb

```
require 'active_record'

module ModuleName
  def self.included(base_class)
    base_class.class_eval do

      include ModuleName::InstanceMethods

      belongs_to :some_model
      before_save :some_method
      .... validations, etc....



    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def some_method
      ....
    end

  end
end
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `self.included` hook.

```
class Ele < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Mod
end

module Mod
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      validates_presence_of :field
    end
  end
end
```